# Setting dates as nullable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having a hard time understanding the inner workings of date fields in laravel. I have a custom date field named `called_at` and I set it as nullable in the schema. Since it's a date field, [I would naturally want it to be a Carbon instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), so in the model I pushed this attribute to the `$dates` array.

```
protected $dates = ['called_at'];
```

In order to be able to set it from the controller, via the `request('called_at')` input, I would have to set a mutator in the model. So I set one like this:

```
public function setCalledAtAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['called_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

But the problem is, even if the user does not provide a date in the input field, the `called_at` attribute is set to the current timestamp! But I expected it to be NULL.

To get rid of it, I commented out the `setCalledAtAttribute` mutator. But now it won't even take the input:

> InvalidArgumentException Data missing

Bottom line, how can I set my date field nullable in such a way that when a user leaves the input field blank, the `called_at` field wont be set to current timestamp?

Comment: Within your migration `$table->timestamp('called_at)` just add `->nullable()` and then re migrate. Or go in to the database and simply allow null on the field.

Comment: I already set it as nullable() in the schema.

Comment: Did it register?

Comment: I mentioned this in the question: "I have a custom date field named `called_at` and I set it as nullable in the schema"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
public function setCalledAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['called_at'] = empty($date) ? null : Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

Comment: It's working. I have a question though. Why does it set the date field to current timestamp even if nothing is inserted in the form?

Comment: @Eisenheim define the date as `->dateTime()` and not `->timestamp()`

Comment: if I define it as dateTime(), will I be able to take empty value from the form?

Comment: Even if I leave it as `timestamp` and don't set it to `dateTime`, your code still works (sets null instead of current date).

Comment: @Eisenheim great. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Eisenheim Note that timestamp fields will automatically update any time the record is created or updated. If you don't want this behaviour, then change it to a datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

If you use parse on an empty string `Carbon::parse('')` or null `Carbon::parse(null)` Carbon will actually [return](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing) the current date and time So you should check if $date is provided and not null:

```
$this->attributes['called_at'] = $date ? Carbon::parse($date); : null;
```

Comment: thanks for making the issue clear. Laravel should have added this in their documentation. Not everyone has prior knowledge on Carbon :(